# Azure app service unable to load AngularJS5 app

Tags: angular, web-hosting, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am trying to publish the AngularJS website (dist folder) to Azure via TeamCity using FTP upload. The files seem to be okay and they are getting uploaded correctly. The App service is running.

But I can only see the landing page of azure app service when I browse the website. [Website link](https://tinywingsstaging3.azurewebsites.net) for your reference.

> The steps on TeamCity are as below
>
> 1. Fetch latest code and do an `npm install`
> 2. Do a `ng build` so that the dist folder gets created and populated.
> 3. FTP upload the dist folder to azure app service

I am using following versions

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.1
@angular/cli: 1.6.0
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

I have also added a web config to see if that fixes anything but to no avail. My web config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="angular cli routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Even if I try to do the FTP upload manually, it is still the landing page that I see. I have tried browsing to `/index` page but then I get resource does not exist. Am I missing some azure app service configuration, required to host an angular app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by changing the `web.config` to the following. I was probably missing out on the correct `regex` for the `match url` tag.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect all reqi=uests" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false"/>
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And then adding the following to `angular-cli.json`. This will automatically include the web config in the `dist` folder while building.

```
 "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
    "web.config"
  ],
```